# meaning of "return this"

Tags: java, android, methods, return

I have been following android tutorial on the internet about SQLite. I got a statement which I'm not sure about:

```
public HotOrNot open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;  
}
```

What does `return this` mean in this method ? is it the current object or context ? thanks

Comment: Current instance of `HotOrNot` on whom this method has been invoked.

Comment: `... the keyword this denotes a value that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was invoked.` [JLS 15.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)

Comment: In other word, as methods (functions) are invoked on objects, this refers to the object on which the current method is called.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`return this` returns the current object instance.  I don't know what `HotOrNot` class is, but it's clear that this method is defined in that class.  In the method, member variable `ourHelper` is initialised with a new database helper and member variable `ourDatabase` is assigned a writable database object from that helper - after which the instance of the class is returned - most likely, so that the calls could be chained, e.g.

```
new HotOrNot(myContext).open().runQuery("some query text")
```

See the [Java language specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) for more information on `this` keyword.